# Android can not perform this action after saveInstanceState when run app via another app

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I have a Fragment with BroadcastReceiver inside, which is contained in Activity. Activity has intent-filter to determine application links. After some actions in fragment I get an e-mail from server with application link. So when I tap on home button on device application doesn't destroy and when I click on link in e-mail, a new fragment must open but I have an IllegalStateException with text `Can not perform this action after saveInstanceState` instead. How to fix it? Below I've attached my activity and two fragments code:

```
public class PerfectoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ProgressUpdater, AuthFragment.ProgressActivator {

    @Bind(R.id.sign_up_progress) ProgressBar mSignUpProgressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_perfecto);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        if (cameFromMail()) {
            if (isSignUpProcess()) {
                mSignUpProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String login = Utils.getLogin(this);
                String password = Utils.getPassword(this);
                String username = Utils.getUsername(this);
                String phone = Utils.getPhone(this);
                Utils.removePasswordAndPhone(this);
                ApiService.startActionAuth(this, login, password);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, SignUpThirdStepFragment.newInstance(username, phone)).commit();
            } else {
                String login = Utils.getLogin(this);
                String resetCode = Utils.getResetCode(this);
                ApiService.startActionCheckConfirmReset(this, login, resetCode);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, ResetPasswordFourthStepFragment.newInstance(login, resetCode)).commit();
            }
        } else {
            Utils.removePasswordAndPhone(this);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new AuthFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    private boolean isSignUpProcess() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.getData() != null) {
            if (intent.getData().getLastPathSegment().equals("confirmreset")) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean cameFromMail() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent.getData() != null)
        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) return true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateProgress(int progress) {
        mSignUpProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
    }

    @Override
    public void activateProgress() {
        if (mSignUpProgressBar.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            mSignUpProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
            mSignUpProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the first fragment

```
public class ResetPasswordSecondStepFragment extends Fragment {


    private static final String BUNDLE_LOGIN = "com.rcd.perfecto.fragments.ResetPasswordSecondStep.bundle.LOGIN";
    public static final String RESET_PASSWORD_FILTER = "com.rcd.perfecto.fragments.filter.RESET_PASSWORD";

    private String mLogin;
    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (!intent.getBooleanExtra(ApiService.EXTRA_SUCCESS, false)) {
                mPhoneErrorTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mPhoneErrorTextView.setText(intent.getStringExtra(ApiService.EXTRA_MESSAGE));
            } else {
                String phone = mLastDigitsEditText.getText().toString();
                String resetCode = intent.getStringExtra(ApiService.EXTRA_DATA);
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, ResetPasswordThirdStepFragment.newInstance(mLogin, phone, resetCode)).commit();
            }
        }
    };

    @Bind(R.id.et_last_digits) EditText mLastDigitsEditText;
    @Bind(R.id.tv_phone_error) TextView mPhoneErrorTextView;

    @OnTextChanged(R.id.et_last_digits)
    void resetPassword(CharSequence digits) {
        if (digits.length() == 4) ApiService.startActionResetPassword(getActivity(), mLogin, mLastDigitsEditText.getText().toString());
    }

    public ResetPasswordSecondStepFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static ResetPasswordSecondStepFragment newInstance(String login) {
        ResetPasswordSecondStepFragment fragment = new ResetPasswordSecondStepFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(BUNDLE_LOGIN, login);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            mLogin =  args.getString(BUNDLE_LOGIN);
        }
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(RESET_PASSWORD_FILTER));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reset_password_second_step, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}
```

And the last one

```
public class ResetPasswordThirdStepFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String BUNDLE_LOGIN = "com.rcd.perfecto.fragments.bundle.LOGIN";
    private static final String BUNDLE_RESET_CODE = "com.rcd.perfecto.fragments.bundle.RESET_CODE";
    private static final String BUNDLE_PHONE = "com.rcd.perfecto.fragments.bundle.PHONE";

    public static final String CHECK_CONFIRM_RESET_FILTER = "com.rcd.perfecto.fragments.filters.CHECK_CONFIRM_RESET";

    private String mResetCode;
    private String mLogin;
    private String mPhone;

    private BroadcastReceiver mConfirmReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (!intent.getBooleanExtra(ApiService.EXTRA_SUCCESS, false)) {
                Utils.showAlert(R.string.reset_password_error, intent.getStringExtra(ApiService.EXTRA_MESSAGE), getActivity());
            } else {
                if (intent.getBooleanExtra(ApiService.EXTRA_DATA, false)) {
                     FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, ResetPasswordFourthStepFragment.newInstance(mLogin, mResetCode)).commit();
                } else {
                    Utils.showAlert(R.string.reset_password_error, getResources().getString(R.string.reset_password_error_desc), getActivity());
               }
            }
        }
    };

    private BroadcastReceiver mSendConfirmationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (!intent.getBooleanExtra(ApiService.EXTRA_SUCCESS, false)) {
                Utils.showAlert(R.string.reset_password_error, intent.getStringExtra(ApiService.EXTRA_MESSAGE), getActivity());
            } else {
                mResetCode = intent.getStringExtra(ApiService.EXTRA_DATA);
                Utils.showAlert(R.string.sign_up_confirmation_link_title, getResources().getString(R.string.sign_up_confirmation_link), getActivity());
            }
        }
    };

    @Bind(R.id.btn_continue) Button mContinueButton;
    @Bind(R.id.tv_not_got_email) TextView mNotGotMailTextView;

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_continue)
    void confirmResetting() {
        ApiService.startActionCheckConfirmReset(getActivity(), mLogin, mResetCode);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.tv_not_got_email)
    void sendConfirmationAgaing() {
        ApiService.startActionResetPassword(getActivity(), mLogin, mPhone);
    }

    public ResetPasswordThirdStepFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static ResetPasswordThirdStepFragment newInstance(String login, String phone, String resetCode) {
        ResetPasswordThirdStepFragment fragment = new ResetPasswordThirdStepFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(BUNDLE_LOGIN, login);
        args.putString(BUNDLE_PHONE, phone);
        args.putString(BUNDLE_RESET_CODE, resetCode);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
           mLogin = args.getString(BUNDLE_LOGIN);
           mPhone = args.getString(BUNDLE_PHONE);
           mResetCode = args.getString(BUNDLE_RESET_CODE);
           Utils.saveLogin(getActivity(), mLogin);
           Utils.savePhone(getActivity(), mPhone);
           Utils.saveResetCode(getActivity(), mResetCode);
        }
          LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mConfirmReceiver, new IntentFilter(CHECK_CONFIRM_RESET_FILTER));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mSendConfirmationReceiver, new IntentFilter(ResetPasswordSecondStepFragment.RESET_PASSWORD_FILTER));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reset_password_third_step, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mConfirmReceiver);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mSendConfirmationReceiver);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are doing some fragment transactions in your BroadcastReceivers, so these operations can be performed when activity is paused and onSaveInstanceState was already called. 
Try using `FragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()` instead of simple `FragmentTransaction.commit();`